# Creating different fragment for every web-service request is correct way or not

Tags: android, web-services, android-fragments, android-volley

I am working on an app which calls various **web-services** for fetching data from server. I am supporting both landscape and portrait mode.
For supporting difference modes I am creating different layouts for landscape and portrait mode.

For calling web-services I am using `Volley` library. For maintaining state of web-service I am creating a `Fragment` with property `setRetainState(true)` and calling web-service inside this fragment and I am passing result to calling activity or fragment through interface.

[here](http://androidresearch.wordpress.com/2013/05/10/dealing-with-asynctask-and-screen-orientation/) is the procedure that I am following currently.

So here I am asking is this the correct way to add a new fragment with `setRetainState(true)` for calling every web service to prevent state of Volley library during orientation change. As this approach include create a new fragment for every request.

Comment: Hey please answer my query

Comment: Are you calling Volley methods in an `AsyncTask`

Comment: No I am calling Volley library in a fragment whose state is set to setRetainState(true). As volley works in background thread so no need to create new thread through AsyncTAsk.

Comment: You wrote you were using an `AsyncTask`. It's right there in your edit history. Listen, **It's ok** to make a mistake. **It's not ok** to edit your question and act like I'm the weird one for asking something unrelated. The right thing to do is say you wrote something by accident, say you edited your question to remove the mistake and clarify your question.

Comment: Sorry Hanski I admit my mistake. I forgot to mention edit comment. Please reply how should I solve this problem.

Comment: I appreciate it. I'm not quite sure I understand your situation. Could you clarify a bit?